# Hightlight column based on todays date

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to highlight today's column -(the header cell)

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Today | Date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | Highlight | - |
| - | - | Highlight | - |
| - | - | Highlight | - |

`=A$1=TODAY()` is not working

Comment: You should apply that formula to range ```A:Z``` (or other last column)

Comment: I am in the field "apply to range" inserting A:Z and in "format cells if.. Custom formula" inserting = A$1= TODAY() however, it is not working

Comment: Then you may have text instead of dates in the first row. Try ```=DATEVALUE(A$1)=TODAY()```

Comment: You are totally right. I am not looking correctly at my own sheet! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dates are in row 1 apply to range A1:Z1 this custom formula:

```
=A$1*1=TODAY()
```